# Java Stream IntSummaryStatistics Default Behaviour

Tags: java, java-stream

I've empty list, and after streaming it then get summary statistics as below,

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        IntSummaryStatistics intSummaryStatistics = list.stream()
                .mapToInt(a -> a)
                .summaryStatistics();
        System.out.println(intSummaryStatistics.getMin());
        System.out.println(intSummaryStatistics.getMax());
```

My output is,

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

Could you please some one give me insight? Why is the int range printed? I understand the lazy init for intermediate operation. Is the output related to that somehow?